# How to import a multiband image into IDL?

Tags: envi

I want to run mathematical calculation on monthly NDVI images from april to october. I stacked monthly NDVI images through april to october into an image (with 7 band) using ENVI. Now I wanna import this image into IDL. How can I do this? What kind of function or procedure should be written?

Please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Have you written IDL .pro programs before?  It has a couple of functions such as READU and READ_BINARY.  You'll need to know your data type (integer, float, etc.), the interleave (bip, bil, or bsq), and possibly the number of samples, lines, and bands if there's no .hdr associated with your binary dataset.  Here's a starting point to get an overview of reading binary data:

http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Reading_Binary_Data.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option, assuming you're running ENVI 4.x or ENVI 5.0 (Classic) + IDL (i.e not ENVI runtime), is to click File->Export to IDL variable.